# Transform hashtags to link

Tags: php, string

Now my second problem is, my script doesn't recognize the second hashtag.
For instance,

```
#heavy / machine gun #test
```

returns:

```
<a href="tag.php?id=heavy+">#heavy</a> / machine gun #test
```

My code is:

```
$words = preg_split("/(#[^\s+[:space:]]+ )/", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
foreach($words as $var => $value)
{
    if($value[0]=='#')
    {
     $test[$var]='<a href="tag.php?id='.urlencode(substr($value,1)).'"> '.$value.'</a>';

     $str=str_replace($value,$test[$var],$descrip);
    } 
}
```

The first hashtag is a link but not the second one...

Thanks in advance,
Jeremie.

Comment: hashtag? Are we talking about Twitter here?

Comment: Or a custom system? (To add to Rene)

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: <a href="tag.php?id=heavy+">#heavy</a> / machine gun <a href="tag.php?id=test+">#test</a>

Comment: Try using this regex `(#[\w]+)` — it should capture both tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
$text = "#heavy / machine gun #test";

$text = preg_replace('/#(\w+)/', '<a href="tag.php?id=$1">#$1</a>', $text);
// or
// $text = preg_replace('/#([^\s+[:space:]]+)/', '<a href="tag.php?id=$1">#$1</a>', $text);

echo $text;
```

html output

```
<a href="tag.php?id=heavy">#heavy</a> / machine gun <a href="tag.php?id=test">#test</a>
```

visual output

[#heavy](https://stackoverflow.com/?id=heavy) / machine gun [#test](https://stackoverflow.com/?id=test)

Comment: Shouldn't the second parameter in preg_replace be `'<a href="tag.php?id=$1">#$1</a>'`? There doesn't need to be a space at the start, plus I imagine he wants the hashes to remain.

Comment: @SimoneNigro I was going to, but then saw the thing about not editing tiny/one character things unless necessary, so wasn't sure if it counted. Still new to SO.

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work for #b&w i mean the link is there but it returns tag.php?id=b

Comment: i found a working solution on RegExr #([a-zA-Z]+[^\s+]+)
actually it's just the & in the url that was the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a trailing space in your regex, that's why if the last word in the sentence is a hashtag, it won't detect it: it has no trailing space.

If I change your regex to

```
$str='omg the are using #heavy / machine gun #test';
$words = preg_split("/(#[^\s+[:space:]]+)/", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

I get:

```
var_dump($words)
array(4) { [0]=> string(18) "omg the are using " 
           [1]=> string(6) "#heavy" 
           [2]=> string(15) " / machine gun " 
           [3]=> string(5) "#test" 
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the answer

```
 $descrip = preg_replace('/#(\w+)/', ' <a href="tag.php?id=$1">#$1</a>', $descrip);
```

Thanks guys for your help